# REGEX for capturing only words?

Tags: dart

here is a text I want to split its words in a list, but the problem is there are commas, periods and a big spacing between the two paragraphs, so can one any suggest a REGEX for extracting only whole words using `split(RegExp())`  method?

input:

```
String text = '''
You find so many people are fimble
But you, you are mostly humble

I love the way you wear your hair,
Spreading your style everywhere.
You're like a style fountain.
Enough for a whole mountain.
''';
```

desired output:

```
[You, find, so, many, people, are, fimble, But, you, you, are, mostly, humble, I, love, the, way, you, wear, your, hair, Spreading, your, style, everywhere, You're, like, a, style, fountain, Enough, for, a, whole, mountain]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see the same question was asked on Reddit where I gave my answer. This is a copy of my solution for the problem.

Also, I would not use `split` in this case but just use the `RegExp` class to get matches which is much simpler since it is easier to define what we define a word to be instead of trying to define what we want to delete. So something like this would do the trick:

```
void main() {
  const text = '''

You find so many people are fimble

But you, you are mostly humble

I love the way you wear your hair,

Spreading your style everywhere.

You're like a style fountain.

Enough for a whole mountain.

''';

  final words = [...RegExp(r"[\w']+").allMatches(text).map((e) => e.group(0))];
  print(words);

  // [You, find, so, many, people, are, fimble, But, you, you, are, mostly,
  // humble, I, love, the, way, you, wear, your, hair, Spreading, your, style,
  // everywhere, You're, like, a, style, fountain, Enough, for, a, whole,
  // mountain]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try var newVar = text.split(' ')

Find it here :
https://www.tutorialkart.com/dart/dart-split-string/

Comment: text.split(' ') don't split the "\n" character, in your case you have if the string contains \n such as the example you have some wrong element inside the list

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can do with the regex the same thing, I don't like to use regex if I can use the logic to make a logic split inside the string.

I'm proposing a draft code to make your solution customizable without worry about the regex logic. Maybe you need to return on the split login to two years from now!

```
void main() {

 
  String value = '''
You find so many people are fimble
But you, you are mostly humble

I love the way you wear your hair,
Spreading your style everywhere.
You're like a style fountain.
Enough for a whole mountain.
''';
  //Inside the text can be a , ., in this case I use the solution to introcuce a not usual token inside
  //inside the list and after split for this token.
  var tokenBySpace = value.split(' ').join("#").split("\n").join("#").split("#");
  
  tokenBySpace = tokenBySpace.map((word) => word = cleanString(word.trim())).toList();
  tokenBySpace.removeWhere((item) => item.isEmpty); //Easy solution to remove the " . " string
  print(tokenBySpace);
  
}

String cleanString(word){
  var grammarRules = [".", ",", "(", ")"];
  
  grammarRules.forEach((rule) => {
    
    if(word.contains(rule)){
      word = word.replaceAll(rule, '')
    }
    
  });
  
  return word;
}
```

The result is

[You, find, so, many, people, are, fimble, But, you, you, are, mostly, humble, , I, love, the, way, you, wear, your, hair, Spreading, your, style, everywhere, You're, like, a, style, fountain, Enough, for, a, whole, mountain]

A solution inside one line can be

```
void main() {

 
  String value = '''
You find so many people are fimble
But you, you are mostly humble

I love the way you wear your hair,
Spreading your style everywhere.
You're like a style fountain.
Enough for a whole mountain.
''';
  //Inside the text can be a , ., in this case I use the solution to introcuce a not usual token inside
  //inside the list and after split for this token.
  var tokenBySpace = value.split(' ').join("#")
    .split("\n").join("#")
    .split(".").join("#")
    .split(",").join("#")
    .split(":").join("#")
    .split(";").join("#")
    .split("#");
  
  tokenBySpace.removeWhere((item) => item.isEmpty); //Easy solution to remove the " . " string
  print(tokenBySpace);
  
}
```

But I preferer the first!

Can you find a complete example [here](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/MyAnswerOnStackOverflow/tree/master/dart/StringSplit)

the code inside the example is reported below

```
void main() {

 
  var value = '''I preferer the previos solution because is more customizzable,
and help you to preserve some exception inside the text, such as URL

In addition, the  this solution, subdivide the logic inside a function.

This solution is made by https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
''';
  //Inside the text can be a , ., in this case I use the solution to introcuce a not usual token inside
  //inside the list and after split for this token.
  var tokenBySpace = value.split(' ').join("#").split("\n").join("#").split("#");
  
  tokenBySpace = tokenBySpace.map((word) => word = cleanString(word.trim())).toList();
  tokenBySpace.removeWhere((item) => item.isEmpty); //Easy solution to remove the " . " string
  print("------------- FIRST SOLUTION -------------------");
  print(tokenBySpace);

  value = '''
  You find so many people are fimble
But you, you are mostly humble

I love the way you wear your hair,
Spreading your style everywhere.
You're like a style fountain.
Enough for a whole mountain.
''';
  
    tokenBySpace = value.split(' ').join("#")
    .split("\n").join("#")
    .split(".").join("#")
    .split(",").join("#")
    .split(":").join("#")
    .split(";").join("#")
    .split("#");
    tokenBySpace.removeWhere((item) => item.isEmpty); //Easy solution to remove the " . " string
    print("------------- FIRST SOLUTION -------------------");
    print(tokenBySpace);

}

String cleanString(word){
  var grammarRules = [".", ",", "(", ")"];
  
  grammarRules.forEach((rule) => {
    
    if(word.contains(rule)){
      word = word.replaceAll(rule, '')
    }
    
  });
  
  return word;
}
```